# How to render Zalgo text in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, fonts, zalgo

GDI+'s DrawString can't seem to render Unicode superscripts and/or subscripts. It shows them as squares and doesn't stack.

**Drawn using DrawString**

[image: drawn by GDI]

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    String text = "ă̡͈̘̠͕̺̯̖̤̺͇̫̗͓̗̤̩̜̩̯̝ͥͪ̍ͯͥ͒ͫ͛ͮ̿ͥ͛́́̈͒ͯ͊̇̿ͪ̓́̋ͨ̌͗̀̾̃ͧ̋͗ͣͦ̑̈̆̚҉̶̸̶̶̷̷̶̸̨̧̧̨̛̛̕͘͘̕͘͜͟͜͜͡͞͠͠͠͏̴̷̴̡̢̀͟͝͠s̸̢̨̥͚̲̝̝̗̤͇͓̫̝͍̥͓̳͕̰̰̙͖̅̾ͨ͗̈́͌̽̋̇ͦ̃͌͌͌̎̃̒̂̆̌ͤ͗̌͂̿̃̋̈́ͦ͂͋͂̽ͪͣ͂ͩ̓̈͆̀͢͜͟͡͠͠͝҉̶̶̧̨̡̧̧̛́́́́̀͘͘̕͢͜͢͢͠͞͠҉́̕͢͝d̵̴̡̡̢̛͙̞̭̲̺̖̯̳̙̞͇͓̖͙̩̩̗̝̮̉̿ͦ͒̓̑̉ͫ̇͒̓̎ͨ̎ͪ̂ͨͨ̿͛͊͛͛͂͐ͭ̄͑̔̄̋̆ͪ̀ͫ͌̉̍́̚̚͘͘͘͟͢͢͞͠͠ͅ҉̴̷̶̶̸̧̢̧̡̢̧̨̛̕͘͘͘͘͘͢͟͡҉f̸̶̵̤̮͚͔̟̮̗̺͖͉̪͔̫͎͓̱̟̰̹̩̈̊ͮͦͯ̅̊ͨ́͊̔ͪ̐ͤ͌̑͋̈́̐͆ͦ̿͌̐̓͐̌͂̅ͩ̄͊͐ͨ̄̄̈́̆̚̚͜͏͏̵̸̧̧̛̛͞͡͡͏̡͘͟͠͏̸̶͏͟͡͞͏̸̡͝͏͠͞͏̴͡͏̢͝";
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 12), Brushes.Black, 30, 30);
}
```

**Drawn using TextRenderer**

[image: Drawn by TextRendere.DrawText]

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 12), new Point(30, 30), Color.Black);
```

**Drawn by firefox**

[image]

How did FireFox manage to draw this properly?

The data I'm using - http://pastebin.com/p5Cp3qUM

Comment: Did you try other fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `TextRenderer.DrawText` instead.

Comment: Times New Roman and Tahoma both show as squares for anything that isnt ascii. I'm on Windows XP.

Comment: It was a font problem. Using "Segoe UI" with font render works.